# Why does my labels are looking different regarding size font bold (xlabel, ylabel, colorbar label)?

Tags: matlab, label

the size/font of my labels at the x-axis and y-axis and colorbar are looking different! why? thank you in advance

%Datei heisst "Testbeispiel_Harald"
    %Der Readtable muss im in D:\work\matlab -> Verzeichnis sein
    clc % löscht den Bildschirm
    clear all % löscht alle Variablen

```
%*************************************************************************
%Hier wird die Matrix eingelesen.
%Klassenbreite - Anzahl Klassen - Startpunkt
%2  6   10 
%2  8   0
%Jetzt kommt das wirkliche Daten
%x-Wert - y-Wert - Häufigkeit
%12 0   10
%14 0   30
%16 0   54
%18 0   51
%20 0   35
%22 0   12
%14 2   25
%16 2   35
%*************************************************************************

%Als Input wünsche ich mir den linken unteren Punkt!!!!

%Einlesen der Daten
Input_Matrix = textread('Testbeispiel_RainflowX.txt')
%Input_Matrix=rand(10,3);


%Bestimmung der Größe der Matrix die als .txt eingelesen wird
[zeilen,spalten]=size(Input_Matrix)%analysiert die grösse der eingelesenen txt datei

%***********Auslesen spezifischer Daten der Matrix"*********************************
Haeufigkeit=Input_Matrix(3:zeilen,3)%(:,3)%gesamte dritte Spalte (exkl. die ersten 2 Zeilen)
ycord=Input_Matrix(3:zeilen,2)%gesamte x-Koordianten (exkl. die ersten 2 Zeilen)
xcord=Input_Matrix(3:zeilen,1)%gesamte y-Koordinaten (exkl. die ersten 2 Zeilen)
x_Klassenbreite=Input_Matrix(1,1) %Wie breit ist die Klasse in x
y_Klassenbreite=Input_Matrix(2,1) %Wie breit ist die Klasse in y
x_Klassen=Input_Matrix(1,2) %Klassenanzahl x
y_Klassen=Input_Matrix(2,2) %Klassenanzahl y
x_Start=Input_Matrix(1,3) %KS Startwert in x
y_Start=Input_Matrix(2,3) %KS Startwert in y


%************Berechnungen für die Achsendarstellungen**********************
x_Achse_Start=x_Start; %Startpunkt auf x-Achse
y_Achse_Start=y_Start; %Startpunkt auf x-Achse
x_Achse_Ende= x_Klassen * x_Klassenbreite+x_Achse_Start %EndWert auf der x-Achse
y_Achse_Ende= y_Klassen * y_Klassenbreite+y_Achse_Start %%EndWert auf der y-Achse

n=10; % höchst zulässige Teilung lt. Harald

if x_Klassen > n
x_Teilung = n;
else
x_Teilung = x_Klassen;
end

if y_Klassen > n
y_Teilung = n;
else
y_Teilung = y_Klassen;
end


%x_Achse_thicks = (x_Achse_Ende-x_Achse_Start)/10 %x-Achse Teilung
%y_Achse_thicks = (y_Achse_Ende)/10 %x-Achse Teilung

%Mit diesem Befehl erzeuge ich die 
x_Achse_thicks1 = round(linspace(x_Achse_Start,x_Achse_Ende,x_Teilung))
y_Achse_thicks1 = round(linspace(y_Achse_Start,y_Achse_Ende,y_Teilung))

%figure;
figure1 = figure('Color',[1 0.968627452850342 0.921568632125854]);

%Punkte_Matrix => Matrix deren Inhalt die Koordinaten aller Eckpunkte der Rechtecke hat
%Größe => (x Zeilen/ 2 Spalten) 
%Benötigte Größe der Punkte_Matrix definieren bzw. alle Werte mit Null initalisieren:
Anzahl_Zeilen_Punkte_Matrix=(zeilen-2)*4;
Anzahl_Spalten_Punkte_Matrix=2;%Fixwert 2 Spalten
Punkte_Matrix = zeros(Anzahl_Zeilen_Punkte_Matrix,Anzahl_Spalten_Punkte_Matrix);
Connections = reshape(1:Anzahl_Zeilen_Punkte_Matrix,4,[])';%Erzeugt eine Matrix für die 
%korrekte Verbindung der Rechtecks-Punkte
value=length(ycord);
%Punkte_Matrix mit den Startwerten initalisieren
%X Werte
x=1;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,1)=xcord(i);
  x=x+4
end

%Punkte_Matrix mit den Startwerten initalisieren
%y Werte
x=1;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,2)=ycord(i);
  x=x+4
end

%Punkte_Matrix mit Punkt2 befüllen
%y Werte
x=2;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,1)=xcord(i)+x_Klassenbreite;
  x=x+4
end

x=2;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,2)=ycord(i);
  x=x+4
end

%Punkte_Matrix mit Punkt3 befüllen
%y Werte
x=3;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,1)=xcord(i)+x_Klassenbreite;
  x=x+4
end

x=3;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,2)=ycord(i)+y_Klassenbreite;
  x=x+4
end

%Punkte_Matrix mit Punkt4befüllen
%y Werte
x=4;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,1)=xcord(i);
  x=x+4
end

x=4;
for i = 1:value  
  Punkte_Matrix(x,2)=ycord(i)+y_Klassenbreite;
  x=x+4
end


set_Output=patch('Faces',Connections,'Vertices',Punkte_Matrix,'FaceVertexCData',Haeufigkeit,'FaceColor','flat','EdgeColor','none') %Befehl fürs "zeichnen"
colormap(jet(256)) %die zahl sagt mir wieviele farben ich nutze => smooth
%figure1 = figure('Color',[1 0.968627452850342 0.921568632125854]);
label_colorbar=colorbar
ylabel(label_colorbar,'Cycles [-]','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
[maxValue, rowIdx] = max(Haeufigkeit(:,1),[],1)
caxis([0,maxValue]) % setzt die color limits 
title('Harald will keine Überschrift Platzhalter','FontSize',14);% Create title
xlabel('Mean Value [MPa]','FontWeight','bold');% Create label
ylabel('Amplitude [MPa]','FontWeight','bold');% Create label
legend('Legende brauchen wir auch keine');
axis([x_Achse_Start x_Achse_Ende 0 y_Achse_Ende])
grid off
set(gca,'XTick',x_Achse_thicks1)
set(gca,'YTick',y_Achse_thicks1)
set(gca,'XGrid','off','YGrid','off','ZGrid','off'); %Raster abschalten
%set_Output.Position = [12, 13, 21, 12];

%gca.XTickLabelRotation = 45; % bei bedarf
%gca.YTickLabelRotation = 45; % bei bedarf
%set(gca,'YTickLabel',{''})
%set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-pi','-pi/2','0','pi/2','pi'})
%set(gca, 'XTickMode', 'manual', 'XTick', Ticks, 'xlim', [0,20]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify your labels in three lines that I can see:

```
% colobar label
ylabel(label_colorbar,'Cycles [-]','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')

% plot x
xlabel('Mean Value [MPa]','FontWeight','bold');% Create label
% plot y
ylabel('Amplitude [MPa]','FontWeight','bold');% Create label
```

In the first you specify a fontsize that is not the default. If you add the fontsize argument to the other two labels, or remove it from the colorbar, they will probably look the same.

In the future, it is easier to help when you provide a [minimum, verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)